# vba lowest alphanumeric text

Tags: vba, excel

How can I get the lowest alphanumeric cell value from a range of cells? I don't want to sort the cells and I don't want to look at the number values only. If I have the following cells:

```
2A1111
4B0011
2Z0011
2A0011
```

Excel should know that 2A0011 is the lowest value since it will sort them correctly as:

```
2A0011
2A1111
2Z0011
4B0011
```

In my macro, I am comparing the values of each cell in a row to the lowest valued cell in that row.  If a cell has a higher value, a new (blank) cell is added in its place and the entire column below the cell shifts down.

```
For cell = 1 To rLastCell.Columns.Count
    If Cells(row, cell) > Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rLastCell.Rows(row)) Then
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2, rLastCell(row, cell))
        Else
            Set rng2 = rLastCell(row, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This works great with all of the rows with numbers-only in my spreadsheed, but when the row contains alphanumeric text, the `.Min(rLastCell.Rows(row))` has a value of 0 and therefore moves every cell in the row down.

As a side note - almost all of the posts I have seen related to this involve ignoring the letter in the cell which means that 2A0011 and 2Z0011 are viewed as equal.

Edit: @Ditto I don't have enough rep to post a screenshot so I'll try to format it out below...

```
2807516 1153634 1153634 3332241

3332241 2319999 2319999 3344644

3344644 2420083 2420083 3347024

3347024 2734988 2734988 3349486

3349486 2807516 2807516 3353163
```

The above will get reformated to the table below.

```
------- 1153634 1153634 ------- 

------- 2319999 2319999 ------- 

------- 2420083 2420083 ------- 

------- 2734988 2734988 ------- 

2807516 2807516 2807516 ------- 

3332241 ------- ------- 3332241

3344644 ------- ------- 3344644

3347024 ------- ------- 3347024

3349486 ------- ------- 3349486

------- ------- ------- 3353163
```

Below, is an example of some alphanumeric data

```
2P9864  0V5170  0V5170  2P9864

5N7531  2P9864  2P9864  2W8150

3N8572  3L0415  3L0415  3N8572

5N7531  5N7531  4W1704  5N7531

6F5985  6F5985  5N7531  6F5985
```

Sorry about the terrible formatting. There is NOT a good way to post tables!

Comment: So I assume the data is unsorted?  and you are unable to sort it ?  So the question becomes: "How do we find the lowest string in an unsorted list ?"

Comment: @Ditto, Each column is sorted, with numerical values, lowest to highest, at the top of the column and alphanumeric values, lowest to highest, below the numeric only values. Not every column contains a given value, if it doesn't, the macro inserts a blank cell and shifts the rest of the column down. Let me know if that needs more explaining.

Comment: Post some sample data, please .. (ie 3 cols, 5 rows should be enough to see/work with)

Comment: @Ditto - Data posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data works good like that .. as a screenshot, I wouldn't be able to view it here (from work), now would I be able to copy/paste it ;)

Here's what I came up with based on what you show ... Not sure it's the most optimal way, however, it does work. Hoping if anyone else spots an easier way (I'm actually kind of hoping there's a function I don't know about) :)

```
  Function f_strmin(in_range As Range) As String
      Dim lowstr As String
      Dim firstpass As Boolean
      firstpass = True

      For Each cell In in_range
          If firstpass And cell.Value <> "" Then
              lowstr = cell.Value
              firstpass = False
          ElseIf cell.Value = "" Then
              ' do nothing
          ElseIf cell.Value < lowstr Then
              lowstr = cell.Value
          End If
      Next cell

      f_strmin = lowstr
  End Function

  Sub test()
      Dim r As Integer
      Dim vr As String
      Dim minval As String
      Dim chk As Boolean

      r = 1
      vr = Trim(Str(r)) & ":" & Trim(Str(r))

      ' as long as the current row we're on has records .. keep going until we hit a blank row
      Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(vr)) > 0
          ' get the min value in this row
          minval = f_strmin(Range(vr))

          For c = 1 To 4
              If Cells(r, c).Value > minval Then
                  chk = Cells(r, c).Insert(xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove)
              End If
          Next c

          r = r + 1
          vr = Trim(Str(r)) & ":" & Trim(Str(r))
      Loop

  End Sub
```

This set:

```
  2807516   1153634 1153634 3332241
  3332241   2319999 2319999 3344644
  3344644   2420083 2420083 3347024
  3347024   2734988 2734988 3349486
  3349486   2807516 2807516 3353163
```

Ends up as this:

```
            1153634 1153634 
            2319999 2319999 
            2420083 2420083 
            2734988 2734988 
  2807516   2807516 2807516 
  3332241                      3332241
  3344644                      3344644
  3347024                      3347024
  3349486                      3349486
                               3353163
```

This set:

```
  2P9864    0V5170  0V5170  2P9864
  5N7531    2P9864  2P9864  2W8150
  3N8572    3L0415  3L0415  3N8572
  5N7531    5N7531  4W1704  5N7531
  6F5985    6F5985  5N7531  6F5985
```

Results in this:

```
            0V5170  0V5170  
  2P9864    2P9864  2P9864   2P9864
                             2W8150
            3L0415  3L0415  
                             3N8572
                    4W1704  
  5N7531    5N7531  5N7531   5N7531
  3N8572            
  5N7531            
  6F5985    6F5985           6F5985
```